# Sample XML databases?

Tags: sql, xml, database, xquery, sample

Are there any notable (large) sample XML databases?

For SQL there are the world and Sakila sample MySQL databases, for example.  However a similar Google search for a good XML sample database doesn't give much besides tiny examples at [(not)w3]schools.com which are clearly insufficient for trying out XQuery.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are some random ones for you:

PMC Open Access Subset
Formats: NLM, Dublin Core

Contains a mixture of full-text journal articles (NLM) and article metadata (DC).

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/about/openftlist.html

XMLDatasets.net
List of publicly available XML data.

http://www.xmldatasets.net/

Answer (score 2):

There's nice juicy XML here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/wurfl/files/WURFL/2.3/

Answer (score 1):

There's Always the [Stack Exchange Data Dump](http://www.clearbits.net/creators/146-stack-exchange-data-dump).  It's quite large, and is in XML Format.  However, it isn't very interesting from an XQuery perpective, because it's basically a flat file (like CSV) encoded as xml attributes.

Answer (score 1):

The US Patent Office has some samples at http://www.uspto.gov/products/xml-resources.jsp.